# Xcode Localization & Internationalization: Exporting for Localization (XLIFF) does not export Info.plist entries

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, info.plist, xliff

I have the common Info.plist that I want to localize. I also have the InfoPlist.strings which has `InfoPlist.Strings (Spanish)` and `InfoPlist.Strings (Base)`.

[image]

My problem is that when I go to `Editor > Export for Localizations...` the XLIFF file it generates does not have any of the Info.plist entries I need to localize in Spanish (My Base localization is English). It also won't include anything I've manually added InfoPlist.strings.

If I manually add them to the `XLIFF`, the entries I add get deleted upon Import. If I manually add them to the InfoPlist.Strings (Spanish) and then export, the entries I manually added get wiped out.

I really am at a loss here on how to localize my plist file because whatever direction I go, the entries get deleted.

There's an InfoPlist.strings in my `es.lproj` and my `base.lproj` folders.

I have to say the *only* entry that doesn't get wiped out is in my Spanish file for `CFBundleName`.

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @guido - Sort of. See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was *able* to get this working but not in a way that was so obvious.

First, I removed the `InfoPlist.strings` file from Xcode and then closed Xcode completely.

I then opened my project folder and manually created an `InfoPlist.strings` file in each of my `lproj` folders. I named each one the same: `InfoPlist.strings`.

I did this even for the English `lproj` folder even though my strings would fall into the base `lproj` folder.

Re-open Xcode.

Even though these still don't export via `Export for Localizations...` option in the `Editor` menu, I had to manually do it within Xcode. Exporting/Importing didn't seem to mess with these files and fortunately, `Info.plist` files don't have much that needs translating.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Mario. Unfortunately I have some custom plists too. Looking forward to a lot of copy pasting :-)

Comment: @guido I'm sorry about that! :( Yeah, I had to do some copy and pasting too. I was able to leave my English plist blank because I was using my Base as my ultimate fallback for translations.

Answer (score 0):

Change the InfoPlist.strings localization from Base to English, then everything works fine for both export and import.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a plist key that I added manually, and just by adding that key to both Base and English localizations before exporting it didn't delete the custom string anymore. (Adding it to the English localization seems to be key here)